# Why such an overhead for system with docker containers usage?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a following question. I was designing recently a java application on Spring, that works with a database. And I have decided to perform a stress testing. Both the application and the database reside on a virtual Debian machine. I tested it with gatling, and here is what I got:

> request count                                        600 (OK=600    KO=0     )
>
> min response time                                     12 (OK=12     KO=-     )
>
> max response time                                    159 (OK=159    KO=-     )
>
> mean response time                                    21 (OK=21     KO=-     )
>
> std deviation                                         13 (OK=13     KO=-     )
>
> response time 50th percentile                         17 (OK=17     KO=-     )
>
> response time 75th percentile                         22 (OK=22     KO=-     )
>
> mean requests/sec                                  10.01 (OK=10.01  KO=-     )
>
> t < 800 ms                                           600 (100%)
>
> 800 ms < t < 5000 ms                                   0 (  0%)
>
> t > 5000 ms                                            0 (  0%)
>
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)

So far, so good. Ater that, I decided to put the database and jar into two containers. Here is a docker-compose.yml sample for that:

```
  prototype-db:
    build: prototype-db
    volumes:
       - ./prototype-db/data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
       - ./prototype-db/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
    ports:
       - "3306"
  prototype:
    image: openjdk:8
    command: bash -c "cd /deploy && java -jar application.jar" 
    volumes:
      - ./application/target:/deploy
    depends_on:
      - prototype-db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    dns:
      - 172.16.10.1
      - 172.16.10.2
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mysql:5.7.15

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=document \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
    MYSQL_USER=testuser \
    MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345

EXPOSE 3306
```

Now, after testing that with gatling I've got the followin results:

---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------

```
request count 6000 (OK=3946 KO=2054 )
min response time 0 (OK=124 KO=0 )
max response time 18336 (OK=18336 KO=77 )
mean response time 5021 (OK=7630 KO=10 )
std deviation 4136 (OK=2478 KO=9 )
response time 50th percentile 6516 (OK=8694 KO=9 )
response time 75th percentile 8732 (OK=8905 KO=14 )
mean requests/sec 87.433 (OK=57.502 KO=29.931)
```

---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------

```
t < 800 ms 65 ( 1%)
800 ms < t < 5000 ms 532 ( 9%)
t > 5000 ms 3349 ( 56%)
failed 2054 ( 34%)
```

---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------

```
java.io.IOException: Remotely closed 1494 (72.74%)
status.find.is(200), but actually found 500 560 (27.26%)
```

This is amazing - the mean response time exceeded drastically, and a lot of errors, but this docker compose system runs on the very same virtual debian machine. What could cause exactly such an overhead, I thought that docker containers are a lot like native processed, they should not be running that slow.

Comment: Can you add the output of `docker info`? As I understand it, you are running compose directly on the VM? Or is Docker for Windows/Mac involved?

Comment: First of all, are you sure those setups are comparable (same java version/vendor, same mysql version, etc)? Also a lot of requests ended with code 500. What your app logs show about this?

Comment: Directly on VM. Mysql version and java version are the same. Although I am not quite sure about the parameters, that is JAVA_OPTS, what kind of memory it uses, I'll check that

Comment: Are you running Docker for Mac, or are you running Docker natively on Linux?

Comment: @jkinkead it runs natively on Debian